# Type Mismatch Object and Integer

Tags: json, object, types, roku, brightscript

```
m.CurrDateObject = FindCurrDateObject(m.itemContent.date)
?"title :"m.CurrDateObject.title //Here I got Type Mismatch Error When 0 comes
?"text :"m.CurrDateobject.text
```

'FindCurrDateObject Return Object when if condition true in function
'when if condition false then it's return 0
'Here, I received two different data types on the function

1. If Condition true => Object
2. If Condition false => 0 as Integer

Can anyone suggest How can I manage this two data types on Roku?

```
function FindCurrDateObject(date as Integer) as Object
    m.date = CreateObject("roDateTime")
    m.myObject = {}
    for each item in m.global.itemArray
        now = m.date.AsSeconds()
                if (now >= date) then
                            m.myObject.title = item.title
                            m.myObject.text = item.text
                            return m.myObject 
                 //This below-mentioned part works, but it's called every time. I don't want to return the invalid value
                 'else 
                 'return invalid                      
             end if
    end for
end function
```

Answer (score 0):

The function *FindCurrDateObject* can be improved like this-

```
function FindCurrDateObject(date as Integer) as Object
    date = CreateObject("roDateTime")
    myObject = {}
    now = m.date.AsSeconds()
    for each item in m.global.itemArray
        if (now >= date)
            myObject.title = item.title
            myObject.text = item.text
            exit for
        end if 
    end for
    return myObject
end function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function FindCurrDateObject(dateAsSeconds as Integer) as Object
    dateTimeObj = CreateObject("roDateTime")
    timeNowAsSeconds = dateTimeObj.AsSeconds()
    m.myObject = {}
    for each item in m.global.itemArray
        if (timeNowAsSeconds >= dateAsSeconds) then
            m.myObject.title = item.title
            m.myObject.text = item.text
            return m.myObject 
        else 
            return Box(0) // This will return roInteger object                     
        end if
    end for
end function
```

Comment: no need to `box()` it explicitly, tbe `as Object` declaration does it implicitly. The issue is elsewhere - trying to reach `CurrDateObject.title` on the returned result of `Integer 0`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can modify your code:

```
m.CurrDateObject = FindCurrDateObject(m.itemContent.date)

if (m.CurrDateObject <> 0)
    ? "title: " m.CurrDateObject.title
    ? "text: " m.CurrDateObject.text
else 
    ? "No valid date object found"
end if
```

In this code, we first check if `m.CurrDateObject` is not 0. If it's not 0, we know it's an object and we can safely access its properties. If it is 0, we print a message indicating that no valid date object was found.

Also, in your `FindCurrDateObject` function, you should return 0 if no matching date is found:

```
function FindCurrDateObject(date as Integer) as Object
    date = CreateObject("roDateTime")
    myObject = {}

    for each item in m.global.itemArray
        now = date.AsSeconds()
        if (now >= date) then
            myObject.title = item.title
            myObject.text = item.text
            return myObject
        end if
    end for

    return 0 ' Return 0 if no matching date is found

end function
```

This way, the function always returns a value, either an object or 0, and you can handle each case appropriately in your main code.